# Correct usage of ap_set_content_type() in apache 2.2

Tags: c++, c, apache

I'm having some trouble using the ap_set_content_type() function in an apache 2.2 module.
The following code is in a function called by my module handler function.

```
std::string type = "text/html";
char content_type[50] = "text/plain";
if (type != "")
{
    memset(content_type, 0, 50);
    type.copy(content_type, 50);
}
ap_set_content_type(r, content_type);
ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_NOERRNO | APLOG_NOTICE, 0, r->server,
        "content-type = %s, then content-type = %s",
        content_type, r->content_type);
```

The intention is that "text/plain" is the default if no other type is specified, and the string `type` will change in value in the future.

The log entry does, as I'd expect, show the value on both occasions to be "text/html", but when the header reaches the client it has been scrambled, and mostly seems to contain special characters, often extended ASCII.

I should also point out that this function is linked using C++, with the apache-specific sections of code in an `extern "C"` block.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I haven't found much good documentation for the apache module API so far, so there is an element of guesswork in this.

This code is running on linux only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `r->content_type` is simply a *pointer* to what you set in `ap_set_content_type`, and your `content_type` variable is local in a function that you leave before the response is sent.

As you know, local variables goes out of scope once a function returns, and all pointers to them become invalid.

Comment: I had guessed that this may be the case. Any idea how I might get around this? There must be some other apache function I need to call to allocate some global memory maybe?

Comment: @user2649502 Just for test, try making the buffer `static` to see if it solves the problem. I don't suggest it as a long-term solution, just for test. Long-term you might have to dynamically allocate (`new`/`strdup`/whatever Apache function there is) the buffer, and free it when the response have been sent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think I've just found the answer. Each request gets an apache "pool" of memory, from which the function apr_palloc() can allocate. I've just tested using that and it seems to work. I presume apache itself will de-allocate this pool for me once the request is done.